# How to prevent Android Studio from creating activity_horizontal_margin when creating the activity through the wizard/template

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time  I create a new activity through the android studio's wizard, I have all these margins created by default on the activity xml

- activity_vertical_margin
- activity_horizontal_margin
- activity_horizontal_margin
- activity_vertical_margin

I end up removing them since I don't need it most of the time and is there a way to prevent this?